# How to create video player in php with play & fullscreen button?

Tags: php, html, video, embed

I have got the below code from internet for embedding a video player but it doesn't have play/pause button or fullscreen option.

Here is the code:

```
<OBJECT ID="MediaPlayer" WIDTH=320 HEIGHT=342
    CLASSID="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95"
    STANDBY="Loading Windows Media Player components..."
    TYPE="application/x-oleobject">

    <PARAM NAME="movie" VALUE="<?php echo $path.'/'.$_POST['file']; ?>">
    <EMBED TYPE="application/x-mplayer2"
        SRC="<?php echo $path.'/'.$_POST['file'];?>"
        NAME="MediaPlayer"
        WIDTH=320
        HEIGHT=342>
    </EMBED>
</OBJECT>
```

Any code fix please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use some free flash based player and embed this on the website, this code you have pasted here - with windows media player - works very badly.

Beside it's very insecure. Easy to do cross site scripting if you don't filter _POST/_GET/

http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/

Comment: Free for non-commercial use, if you use it commercially there's e60 for a license. You can probably find something free for commercial use too, but this one is the best stock player available ATM.

Answer (score 2):

```
<OBJECT ID="MediaPlayer" WIDTH="300" HEIGHT="200" CLASSID="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" STANDBY="Loading Windows Media Player components..." TYPE="application/x-oleobject">
<PARAM NAME="FileName" VALUE="<?php echo $path.'/'.$POST_['file']; ?>">
<EMBED TYPE="application/x-mplayer2" SRC="<?php echo $path.'/'.$POST_['file']; ?>" NAME="MediaPlayer" WIDTH="200" HEIGHT="200" ShowControls="1" ShowStatusBar="0"       ShowDisplay="0" autostart="0"></EMBED></OBJECT>
```

Answer (score 0):

Users may need plugin to display media player in other browsers other than internet explorer. I recommend you to use a flash based player.

http://www.longtailvideo.com/players

Answer (score -1):

```
{   
 <video width="720" height="430" autoplay  *controls preload="none*">
    <source src="" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="" type="video/ogg">
    //Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>enter code here
}
```

add controls